# How to create chained selects in Rails 4/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-4

```
  <div class="item">
    <%= f.label :category_id, "Category:" %>
    <%= f.select :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :title) %>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <%= f.label :leftcat_id, "Left menu:" %>
    <%= f.select :leftcat_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Leftcat.all, :id, :title) %>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <%= f.label :section_id, "Section:" %>
    <%= f.select :section_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Section.all, :id, :title) %>
  </div>
```

I have this code right here and I'd like to make those selects chained. If a user selects in `Left menu`, for example `Maths` then `Sections` relate to whatever is related to math and so on. How can that be done with the example given above? I know there's an old `chained select` gem for rails 3, but maybe there's a more up to date version of something similar?

Comment: you could just update your drop downs via jQuery and ajax by adding an event handler for the `blur` or similiar event. I use jQuery and jSon to do this basicly make a call to a method an return a valid jSon response then add them to the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

If your collections are small enough, it may be worth skipping the AJAX by pre-loading all the data in JS and doing everything client-side -- I've had success with something like http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript